# Android json parsing can get json response from ws calling from Retrofit?

Tags: android

I am using retrofit lib because it's giving fast response.
But why need always one model class corresponding one ws response of parsing/calling web service using retrofit. Is it possible to get json response directly in my program?

Comment: Did you fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your response inside Response and then access the JSON data using the following:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // Do your success stuff...
        } else {
            try {
                JSONObject jObjError = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), jObjError.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use this as your api call:
`Call<ResponseBody> yourMethod()`. Then in your `onResponse` callback you can get json response via `response.body().string()`. See [javadoc](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html).